# Pentaho Data integration: "group by" with Concatenate strings separated by ";" instead of ","

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have to concatenate strings from different fields. The output should be all strings in on field seperated by semi-colons.

The "Group by" Transformation step does everything i need to do, but I can only separate them with " " or with tabs or with ",". 
The strings i need to concat contain "," themselves so i cant use "," to separate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Group By step has a second operation "Concatenate strings separated by" (without the comma). Using that, you can enter the separator in the value column.

Comment: Thanks so much! My window size was to small, so the value column was not visible. Awesome!